# spring boot System.getProperty("java.class.path") doesn't include lib/ jars

Tags: spring-boot

I've got a spring boot app and I'm building a myApp.jar using the spring-boot antlib.  When I jar -tf myApp.jar I see that I have a jar called lib/foo.jar.  Yet when I print out System.getProperty("java.class.path") I don't see that jar file on the classpath.  I also get a ClassNotFound exception from URLClassLoader when the code attempts to use this class for the first time.  I'm using the JarLauncher since that's what the antlib defaults to.

Any ideas why this jar file would not be on the classpath?

Answer (score 2):

You won't see a bundled JAR in `System.getProperty('java.class.path')`. The class path specifies where the JVM will look in the *filesystem* for classes you attempt to load.

Spring Boot uses fat JARs, which are loaded in a completely different way. Refer to the Spring Boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html).

Comment: so if I need to add something to the classpath that's inside the jar, how do I do that?  I have some 3rd party code that looks on java.class.path to determine if it should load or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, that third party library is not doing things the right way, because as you can see, the class path isn't a reliable indicator of what classes are available to load. In this case, to work with this library, you can't bundle the JAR. It will have to reside separately in the filesystem in a location identified in the class path.